# Getting DialogResult using uiVisualizerservice.Show

Tags: c#, wpf, catel

I was porting a modal dialog to a non-modal one.

My problem is: `uiCompletedEventArgs.Result` is null.

I've seen having the debug exception enabled that the following exception is thrown **"DialogResult can be set only after Window is created and shown as dialog."**

Here is a snippet of my code

```
 var viewmodel = viewModelFactory.CreateViewModel<GenericViewModel>(someIds);

       uiVisualizerService.Show(viewmodel, CompletedProc);
    }

    private async void CompletedProc(object sender, UICompletedEventArgs uiCompletedEventArgs)
    {
        if (uiCompletedEventArgs.Result.HasValue && uiCompletedEventArgs.Result.Value) //here's null
        { ... }
```

How can I tell if a user clicked `Yes` or `Cancel` button?

Thanks for your advice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately you cannot set *DialogResult* when you call window.Show (WPF limitation, it's only possible when using window.ShowDialog). Therefore you will need to do one of the following:

1. Subscribe to the Canceled or Saved events of the view model to check whether it was saved or canceled
2. Create a model that you inject into the vm that holds the state